# Need to lock the text boxes in the login page?

Tags: php, html

need a help..I have created a login page with html and php.By entering email as the username and entering a  password the user can login.But if the user click the login button without filling a text box an error message saying "missing" will display infront of that text box.(username text box,password text box and login button are in the same line)

problem is when that message displays infront of the one textbox the other will move away.it will appear after the word "missing".login button will also move..how can I lock these elements.pleas help.. :(

Comment: post your code or fiddle

Comment: i guess you could set the "missing" text to be "absolute" positioned so that it won't influence the other elements

Answer (score -1, accepted):

add the param in your input line. Example shown to you below, Just add readonly="true"

```
<input type="text" name"mypostvariable" readonly="true">
```

Comment: That's invalid. The only acceptable valid of `readonly` is `"readonly"` … and you're missing the `=` from the `name` attribute.

Comment: You also seem to have given up reading the question after the title. It is about locking the *position* of the element, not the value.